# Is it possible to get the iTunes Store ID for an MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, ios10, itunes-sdk, apple-music

Is there a way to get the iTunes Store ID for a song from an `MPMediaItem`?

I'm trying to pull the user's playlists, transfer those to another device, then play the songs using MPMusicPlayerController's `setQueueWithStoreIDs`. This would require mapping the `MPMediaItem`s to content in the iTunes Store, which is the purpose of iTunes Match, which is included in an Apple Music subscription.

Theoretically, this should be possible for songs that were matched to iTunes content. However, I can't find a property or `valueForKey` on `MPMediaItem` or any other class in `MPMediaPlayer` framework that supports this. The `persistentId` set of properties are local DB keys and don't tie back to the iTunes content for the item. They don't seem to be the same across devices for the same user either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now possible in iOS 10.3+ using the `playbackStoreID` instance property on `MPMediaItem`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/2813404-playbackstoreid

Comment: I guess because it is new, playbackStoreID is not always there. It returns "0" sometimes if there is no a playbackStoreID found. I think we still need to use iTunes search API for a more stable solution.

Comment: I believe `playbackStoreID` will return 0 when the song wasn't matched by iTunes Match

Comment: The `playbackStoreID` will return 0 when the song is available on Apple Music but was bought using the iTunes Store...